# How do I do a strict equals/triple equals comparison in phpunit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, equality, triple-equals

How do I do a ===/strict equals comparison in phpunit?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [assertSame](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertSame).  It checks that the type and value are the same.

For objects, this will check that they "reference the same object" (object identity).

Comment: What is the functions that can compare two different objects, but with exactly the same poperties? Like `assertSame()`, that checks everything excep for the reference.